# Installing Ubuntu 14.04.4 on a Acer TravelMate B116-M results in black screen

Tags: boot, system-installation, acer

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.4 on a Acer TravelMate B116-M-C7T3 N3050 notebook. I do not have another OS on this computer, only Ubuntu.

I downloaded the ISO file ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386.iso and created a bootable USB device.

I disabled UEFI in the BIOS (btw. the version of the BIOS is 1.20).

I can use the Try Ubuntu option and it works well. I also get network connection and I can install Ubuntu to the local drive. After the installation succeeds and I press the restart button, Ubuntu will not boot. I just get a black screen without a cursor or mouse pointer.

When using the GRUB bootmanager and selecting the recovery mode, I get the messages:

> Loading Linux 4.2.0-27-generic ...
>
> Loading initial ramdisk ...

Below is a cursor but it's not blinking. After this, nothing happens. Also, Ctrl-Alt-Del does not work.

I also tried installing Ubuntu directly from the USB device's boot menu (e.g. without choosing the Try Ubuntu option) but nothing changed.

Since I can "Try" Ubuntu, I assume that Ubuntu does in fact run on this notebook. But why isn't it starting from the local drive? What is the difference?

**Update:** Everything works fine if I disable automatic updates during the installation. Installing updates manually brings back the black screen. How can I find out which update causes the problem?

**Update 2:** Couldn't reproduce working installation without updates. Also tried 64 bit version and Lubuntu 15.10. Always ended up with a black screen on startup. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Adding `acpi=off` to the boot options didn't change anything. I don't know what you mean by changing the screen brightness from tty (I'm a linux noobie).

Comment: If you can, you might want to try installing using the mini.iso. I have found this method is quicker, more reliable, and is a really small file ≈ 40 MB http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso See here for more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Here's what I did:

- In the BIOS setup, I enabled the UEFI secure boot option
- I installed Ubuntu 15.10 64 Bit from the USB Device
- Then I had to disable the UEFI secure boot (legacy mode)

Instead of the black screen there's a purple screen now, and after a few seconds there is black screen again. But: If I press Enter, there's some flickering and graphics mode changing going on and afterwards, finally, I can see the login screen and everything works fine.

The only thing that is not working with that device is the hibernation mode. Well, the Acer TravelMate is not a certified Ubunutu device but if you follow the above instruction it seems to work just fine. It's very fast and beautiful.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After you boot up and the screen is black for some time press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Next, **blindly** type in your user name and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Then, type in your password and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Finally, type in the following command and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

To get back to your graphical xsession, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

If this fixes your problem, you may need to do the following after installation.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Edit these two lines

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to read as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

and then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

sources

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1742352

and

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2118083

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't work eighter. I wish I could provide more information but all I get is a black screen...

Comment: @MrSparkle What kind of graphics do you have; I assume you have  intel graphics, correct? Also, sometimes the fix for this is to find the correct keyboard combo to increase the screen brightness and to keep pressing this until you can see the screen.

Comment: @MrSparkle The other thing to do would be to remove "quiet splash" or press F2 during boot to show a verbose output. There may be some useful information printed on the screen if the system is freezing at a certain point during boot. This information may help us tackle and pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @MrSparkle Also, instead of adding `acpi=off` you can try editing grub to include  `acpi_backlight=vendor` and or `acpi_osi=Linux` to get it to work.

Comment: Yes, the notebook has Intel HD graphics. From what I understand, there is no need to install or update drivers for this. Also, Ubuntu runs without problems when booting from a USB device.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but unfortunately without success. The screen turns black as soon as the booting operation starts. But I think it's not black as in "no lights" but as in "no characters on screen". The display backlights are switched on (although I cannot control the brightness using the keyboard). To me, it seems like the computer just stopped or Linux tries booting from the wrong partition, but I don't know how such a situation would look like if it  actually occurs on Linux.

Comment: @MrSparkle Usually, you can tell when something like this happens because the caps lock and number lock lights get frozen and do not change when toggled. If you can still turn caps lock and similar lights on and off, then you don't have a screen. If you cannot turn these lights on and off, the system is failing to boot. Do you get a screen (text only) when you press CTRL+ALT+F1? or CTRL+ALT+F2

Comment: There's no keyboard support at all at this point. So I guess the system is frozen.

Another thing I discovered during another installation: It works fine if I disable connecting to the internet during install. I can start Ubuntu, but after downloading and installing some updates I'm back to the black screen. So I guess it's the updates. What should I do? Installing one more time and disabling all updates?

Comment: @MrSparkle Disabling updates is not a good idea. Try installing 16.04 instead. http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso